# Flashlight problem on Android

Tags: stock-android, flashlight

I have recently faced a problem on Android regarding the flashlight.

When the flashlight is turned 'on', the flashlight icon in the status bar gets highlighted.

When I am turning 'on' the flashlight, it is staying on for sometime and it automatically gets switched off suddenly after some time, but the icon in the status bar still stays highlighted, which indicates that the flashlight is turned on. Same thing happens for the front flashlight.

Can anybody say what can be the reason for this automatic and  random turning off of the  flashlight ?

Additional information : There is no fixed time interval for the automatic switch off, it is occuring randomly.

Comment: I have an opposite issue, my icon will remove itself from the menu all together and i can not turn off the flashlight.... I think android has issues with flash light apps at the best of times... The flash is just that, a flash... Using the LED as a torch is possible, however it's not really designed for it..  Usually overheating causes an issue etc... Most androids in my experience have issues with flash light torch apps.. Even the default Video recorder has limit's on certain device's... A custom application or widget might be an alternative, some apps can handle the flash intensity etc...

Comment: Yes, heating of the flashlight may be a reason, but since I don't use my device so much, it does not get heated. Sometimes, even when the device is cold, the flashlight turns off just a few seconds after it has been turned on.

Comment: As you have said, I have tried many apps, including my self-made apps, but it doesn't seems to solve the issue. Even when I turn on flashlight from the camera app, I face the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like residue, have you used it near water or maybe splashed water on it... It sounds like some kind of short circuit

Comment: If you have root access, Add these build props and try tweaking them..... ro.media.capture.flash=led
ro.media.capture.flashMinV=3300000
ro.media.capture.torchIntensity=65
ro.media.capture.flashIntensity=70

Comment: I think you are right. I haven't ever splashed water over the phone, but the phone had once got dropped while charging. But I can't root my phone, because my parents have still not afforded a PC.

Comment: Let me see, whether system update, wiping cache partition or factory reset can solve this or not. If it doesn't, there must be some hardware issues.

Comment: Some device's can be rooted using Applications directly on the device, i tried several and the most successful ( But also most invasive ) is KingRoot ... At one point, Android 5.1.1 days.. it could root 93% of all androids vulnerable to the Universal signature .. Problem, bug? idk what you'd call it... However, it sends your IMEI number and other unnecessary information to the server while gaining root... Other apps are KingoRoot, Framaroot, Towelroot, Etc.... Have a look around and test a few.  Android 6.0 + may require a custom recovery to gain access by flashing Super SU or Magisk...

Comment: My stock software shuts down my headphones at full volume by stopping whatever is playing... I used Engineer Mode to lower the headphones output and everything works fine... Sometimes it's just bad development or quick development with a few oversights...

Comment: Thanks for your rooting suggestions, but all those programs had failed to root my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a technique to deal with this issue.

I have booted my phone into recovery mode and wiped android's cache partition from there. Since then, the flashlight issue seems to have flown away.
I mean, now the flashlight is not automatically turning itself off.

@Zillinium, I think you should also try this method to deal with your issue. If that doesn't work, a system update or factory reset might do the trick, if there is no hardware problem.

Comment: It's very strange that the cache caused this issue... Anyway I'll give it a try.

Comment: For me, it's not anything strange, because once after restarting my phone, I had noticed that the speaker was not working at all !  From then, I came to the conclusion that software bugs and corrupted cache can affect hardware performance.